# run jquery function after .html()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to execute a slider after html code has been injected into an element, how can I make it wait until all the html has been injected before running the slider function? This is my code, it's underscore code:

```
$(".swiper-wrapper").html(
  _.template(template, {
    looks: looks
  })
```

Comment: `.html()` is synchronous... right?